# How can I configure the SF to notify the customer when attachment is too large and the email failed?

Tags: attachment, email2case, email-alert

I wanna know about NDR (non-delivery report) in SF.

Firstly, what's the maximum size per file in attachment? When these are too large, how can i notify the customer automatically? This feature exists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size you can find it here :
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm

In this post they say they aren't working on this feature :
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KJVWAA4

But i'm not sure if it can be achived some way.
I hope this helps you somehow :)

Comment: It would be very cool if you could extend your answer with a specific data (ie. maximum size, short description of the solution and so on). Thanks.

Comment: Actually, i didnt found a solution, since in the ideas forum the official response was that they were not working on this feature :( 

The especific response would be this one :
The size limit for multiple files attached to the same email is 25 MB, with a maximum size of 5 MB per file.

Comment: On this link : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kjmeAAA
They say they raised a case and upgraded the limi up to 10MB x file. I don't know if it's enough for this case, but maybe could be a solution.